# Sum row and 60 seconds before current row

Tags: pandas

How do I sum row in Value and 60 seconds before current row and output a new column?

```
Time_Stamp              Value       output
2022-08-17 09:43:10     30          30
2022-08-17 09:43:30     10          40
2022-08-17 09:43:45     10          50
2022-08-17 09:43:45     10          60
2022-08-17 09:44:10     20          50
2022-08-17 09:44:10     50          100
2022-08-17 09:44:30     10          100
```

Comment: Don't understand the example. If you sum the row at "2022-08-17 09:44:10", which is 50, and the row 1 minute earlier, which is 30, then you get 80, not 100 as the output.

Comment: Please, consider provide your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) sum:

```
# ensure datetime
df['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time_Stamp'])

df['output'] = df.rolling('60s', on='Time_Stamp')['Value'].sum()
```

Output:

```
           Time_Stamp  Value  output
0 2022-08-17 09:43:10     30    30.0
1 2022-08-17 09:43:30     10    40.0
2 2022-08-17 09:43:45     10    50.0
3 2022-08-17 09:43:45     10    60.0
4 2022-08-17 09:44:10     20    50.0
5 2022-08-17 09:44:10     50   100.0
6 2022-08-17 09:44:30     10   100.0
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I make it work in groups?


Time_Stamp          Value  Group  output


2022-08-17 09:43:10 30  A    30.0


2022-08-17 09:43:30 10  A    40.0


2022-08-17 09:43:45 10  A    50.0


2022-08-17 09:43:45 10  A    60.0


2022-08-17 09:44:10 20  A    50.0


2022-08-17 09:44:10 50  A    100.0


2022-08-17 09:44:30 10  A    100.0


2022-08-17 09:43:10 30  B    30.0


2022-08-17 09:43:30 10  B    40.0


2022-08-17 09:43:45 10  B    50.0


2022-08-17 09:43:45 10  B    60.0

Comment: Almost the same: `df.groupby('Group').rolling...`